# Lines above execv() don't run?

Tags: c

Working on some dups of pipes and was trying to test my program. I tried to print something before execv() and i realised the print doesn't run. Is this normal?

```
if (pid == 0) {
    printf("hi"); // <- does not run
            
    execv(singleProcess[0], (char *const *) singleProcess);
}
```

Comment: `printf()` is called. But the output could have been buffered and the buffer is not flushed when the process is replaced by `execv()`. Try calling `fflush(stdout);` before

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` *is* called. But the output will most probably be buffered and the stdio-buffer is not flushed when the process is replaced by `execv()`.

Normally `stdout` is line buffered and you don't write a Newline. But anyway as long as you don't explicitely set it, I wouldn't rely on any specfic buffering mode.

Just call `fflush(stdout);` after `printf()` and before `execv()` and you will see the output.

Comment: Okay. What about close() and dup2() will they be executed first before execv? In the case where it is before execv().

Comment: Re "*and you don't write a Newline*", That would only help if stdout is connected to a terminal.

Comment: Any command you call before `execv()` will be executed

Comment: @ikegami I know. That's why I said 'wouldn't rely on any specfic buffering mode'.

Comment: Your expecting a lot from someone who probably didn't know about buffering a second ago. My comment fills in a gap.

Comment: @ikegami really? My advice was not to write a newline but to call `fflush()`. I just wrote about line buffering because you will find hints like "add  a newline and you will see the output' dozens of times